# JavaScript/jQuery plugin: snap to grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Trying to add "snap to grid" functionality for [jQuery-select-areas plugin](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas).

[Plugin's GitHub](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas)  and  [Plugin's Demo](https://rawgit.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/master/example/example.html)

There is [one similar plugin](https://github.com/polomoshnov/jQuery-UI-Resizable-Snap-extension), with the functionality I'm looking for,  but it's built for jQueryUI. To be honest, I'm not sure how to connect those.
Appreciate any ideas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin has a [`changing` event](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas#user-content-events) that you can listen to, and the event handler is passed the areas that are created. You are able to manipulate the values of the area by changing the width,height,x, and y properties of that area object.

```
$("#example").selectAreas({
  onChanging: function(event,currentAreaId,areas){
    //use filter on areas to get currently changing area
    var area = areas.filter(area=>area.id==currentAreaId)[0];
    area.width = 50; //set value to nearest grid interval
    area.height = 50; //set value to nearest grid interval
  }
});
```

You can calculate the nearest grid interval using the following statement:

```
Math.round( value / intervalAmount ) * intervalAmount
```

Demo

```js
function nearestInterval(interval,value){ 
  return Math.round(value / interval)*interval; 
}

$("#example").selectAreas({
  minSize: [30, 30],
  maxSize: [400, 300],
  onChanging: function(event,id,areas){
    var area = areas.filter(area=>area.id==id)[0];
    area.width = nearestInterval( 30, area.width );
    area.height = nearestInterval( 30, area.height );
    area.x = nearestInterval( 30, area.x );
    area.y = nearestInterval( 30, area.y );
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/master/resources/jquery.selectareas.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/master/jquery.selectareas.js"></script>

<img id="example" src="https://placebear.com/g/400/250" />
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrick! This works great. I think now I know where to look.